# Gradle error new install of Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I am trying to install Andorid Studio after finishing the installation and creating an android project I am receiving the following errors:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.

org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 available for offline mode.
[enter image description here][1]
and when I go to *.xml layout file I receive "Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync"
```

Searching on google for this issue, I added google() at build.gradle but the issue remains.

Please any kind of help or ideas to fix the problem ? Thnx in advance

Comment: Completely uninstall, re-download, and reinstal. This is not normal.

Comment: Could you attach an image of your gradle (project and all level)

Comment: I have already tried unistall/reinstall the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Disable the offline mode of Gradle by going to File - Project Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle - Remove --offline in Command Line options.(Or, simply click the -//- icon in the Gradle window.)

Then, connect to the internet and run Gradle build.

After the build has run once, you can enable the offline mode again.

Comment: Hi thnx for your answer and your help , I tried it but the issue remains, I also tried to rreinstall / install Android Studio but nothing the issue still remains